# Help! cant seem to get 2FA to work for my AWS ec2 SSH

Tags: ssh, authentication, amazon-ec2, google

Hi I have tried the solution online to include a 2FA system inside. even after I log out it still doesn't require a 2FA and log in as long as a PEM is present and I am not sure what I am doing wrongly

this are the steps that I followed
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Install PAM**

```
$ sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
```

**2. Generate Code**

```
$ google-authenticator
```

Pick up your favorite app (Google Authenticator, Authy...) and add your (QR)code shown at the screen.

**3. Configure SSH**

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Add the following line to the TOP of the file.

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Disable user password authentication by commenting out the following line:

```
#@include common-auth
```

**4. Edit the SSH daemon configuration file:**

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and configure options like:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Followed by:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd && sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

**5. Try to login in another SSH session** while keeping the actual one connected `(in case something goes wrong so you can revert changes.)`